# What is the difference between a 'baseband processor' and 'baseband controller'?

Tags: microcontroller, rf

It seems hard to find a definition for either of the terms.  From skimming through datasheets that contain these terms, I get the impression that both refer to programmable components which control the final RF circuitry.  But what exactly is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The difference, if there is one, is manufacturer specific.  A baseband processor and a baseband controller often perform the same functions - that of controlling every aspect of the RF hardware.

Some manufacturers like to use "baseband processor" in order to  indicate that their controller performs functionality you might find higher on a communications stack, such as message decoding.  For instance a WiFi baseband controller might still need to be attached to a processor to implement a full WiFi link, whereas a baseband processor might handle more of the communications stack and may attach directly to another network interface, USB, etc.

Comment: Thank you. That's what it seems to me, too. Do you know of any citable sources?